# Apache Camel fields injection

Tags: spring, apache, apache-camel

Using Apache Camel PropertyPlaceHolder I want to inject a property value in a Java Class field using Simple Expression Language:

```
@Simple("${properties:prop1}")
private String prop1;
@Simple("${properties:prop2}")
private String prop2;
```

That works fine with method's parameters:

```
public void test(@Simple(value = "${properties:prop}") String prop) {
    //....
}
```

But in java class fields I keep having `null` value, nothing is injected.

Any ideas please on how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
@Simple("${properties:prop2}")
private String prop2;
```

On fields is not supported in Camel.

There is a JIRA ticket to support this in the future: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3215